# Is a sample collected over 10 years sufficient for testing if not random?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, sample

I have aggregated football player box score statistics from the years 2008 - 2018. As a result I have almost 40 thousand observations and I would like to start doing hypothesis testing on this data set.

From what I have read, a lot of observational studies take Simple Random Samples of a population to arrive at point parameters.

My primary question is if I should be taking random samples within my sample for hypothesis testing. As an example, I'd like to test to see if player performance (measured as points) is better in home games. If I use the 10 years of data to find the sample mean of points, can I compare the home mean points to the sample mean to determine significance? Or should I be taking a random sample within this 10 years of data to represent the sample mean?

Appreciate any help or articles/reading I should do.

Comment: You would not sample from the observations you have. Your observations are your sample. You might argue that you have the entire (finite) population, and there are methods for handling finite populations.

Comment: Have you collected all the data from the potential pool of footballers you want to test about? Have you covered all the league and Cup competitions you wish to understand? Your analysis will be specific to the characteristics of the pool of data. Do you want to make generalisations beyond your dataset (other competitions or future projections etc)? Or are you wanting to summarise what the statistics are over that period?

Comment: Hello @ReneBt. Thank you for the responses. I think Dave answered the main question. From a sampling perspective, this is obviously not entirely random. Is there anything wrong with just collecting as much data as possible? Or is it better to choose randomly across a number of years?

Comment: my queries were to understand what you are trying to do. If you are trying to predict or generalise then you need randomn sampling. If you just want to describe, then you use what you have.